# PostgresSQL: How to return function's output in created table inside this function?

Tags: postgresql, function

I need to change the output format of my function, and for that, I decided to create another table inside the function to insert the data in the way my task asks for.

The function must show customer's activity in a time gap.

Necessary output:

[image: 1]

It's a DVD_rental DB.

Firstly, I thought about a temporary table to return the output I need, but I've read somewhere that it's not a good idea. So, I create a usual table inside and filled it will the data from cte.

In my code below I get a syntax error at CREATE TABLE stage:

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "CREATE"
```

Another question is connected with TRUNCATE: I am not sure about if I need to clean up the new table at the end of the function.
How to deal with all of that? I am really puzzled and new to SQL.

Thank you in advance!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.customer_activity(i_client_id integer, left_boundary date, right_boundary date)
RETURNS TABLE (metric_name text, metric_value CHAR(500))
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN 
    RETURN QUERY(
    
        WITH cte_activity AS (
            SELECT c.customer_id, INITCAP(c.first_name || ' ' || c.last_name) || ', ' || lower(c.email) AS "customer's info", 
            COUNT(f.film_id) AS "num. of films rented",
            string_agg(DISTINCT INITCAP(f.title), ', ') AS "rented films' titles", 
            COUNT(p.payment_date) AS "num. of payments",
            SUM(p.amount) AS "payments' amount"
            FROM public.customer c 
            JOIN rental r ON r.customer_id = c.customer_id 
            JOIN inventory i ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id 
            JOIN film f ON f.film_id = i.film_id
            JOIN payment p ON p.rental_id = r.rental_id 
            WHERE r.rental_date BETWEEN left_boundary AND right_boundary AND c.customer_id = i_client_id
            GROUP BY c.customer_id, "customer's info"
            )
            
        CREATE TABLE public.output_table (metric_name text, metric_value CHAR(500))
        
        INSERT INTO output_table (metric_name, metric_value)
        
        VALUES ('customer''s info', (SELECT "customer's info" FROM cte_activity)),
        ('num. of films rented', (SELECT "num. of films rented" FROM cte_activity)), 
        ('rented films'' titles', (SELECT "rented films' titles" FROM cte_activity)), 
        ('num. of payments', (SELECT "num. of payments" FROM cte_activity)), 
        ('payments'' amount', (SELECT "payments' amount" FROM cte_activity))
        SELECT * FROM output_table
        
        TRUNCATE TABLE public.output_table -- do I need it at all??
    )
END;
$$;
```

Comment: Why create a table each time you call the function. It would be much more efficient to simply return the result you want.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I understand, but I don't know how to do that the way it is in the image I attached :)

Answer (score 0):

The creation of the table is useless. You can unpivot the columns from the aggregation directly in the query and return this as the function's result.

Note that using the CHAR data type is discouraged. `text` is a better choice here.

You also don't need PL/pgSQL just to return the result of a query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.customer_activity(i_client_id integer, left_boundary date, right_boundary date)
    RETURNS TABLE (metric_name text, metric_value text)
    LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
    WITH cte_activity AS (
      SELECT c.customer_id, 
            INITCAP(c.first_name || ' ' || c.last_name) || ', ' || lower(c.email) AS "customer's info", 
            COUNT(f.film_id) AS "num. of films rented",
            string_agg(DISTINCT INITCAP(f.title), ', ') AS "rented films' titles", 
            COUNT(p.payment_date) AS "num. of payments",
            SUM(p.amount) AS "payments' amount"
      FROM public.customer c 
        JOIN rental r ON r.customer_id = c.customer_id 
        JOIN inventory i ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id 
        JOIN film f ON f.film_id = i.film_id
        JOIN payment p ON p.rental_id = r.rental_id 
      WHERE r.rental_date BETWEEN left_boundary AND right_boundary 
        AND c.customer_id = i_client_id
      GROUP BY c.customer_id, "customer's info"
    )
    SELECT u.*
    FROM cte_activity a
      cross join lateral (
        VALUES 
          ('customer''s info', a."customer's info"),
          ('num. of films rented', a."num. of films rented"::text), 
          ('rented films'' titles', a."rented films' titles" ), 
          ('num. of payments', a."num. of payments"::text), 
          ('payments'' amount',  a."payments' amount"::text)
      ) as u(metric_name, metric_value);
$$;
```

---

Instead of hardcoding the columns in the final select, this can also be done by converting the row into JSON and then returning the key/values from that. This is a bit more dynamic:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.customer_activity(i_client_id integer, left_boundary date, right_boundary date)
    RETURNS TABLE (metric_name text, metric_value text)
    LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
    WITH cte_activity AS (
      SELECT c.customer_id, 
            INITCAP(c.first_name || ' ' || c.last_name) || ', ' || lower(c.email) AS "customer's info", 
            COUNT(f.film_id) AS "num. of films rented",
            string_agg(DISTINCT INITCAP(f.title), ', ') AS "rented films' titles", 
            COUNT(p.payment_date) AS "num. of payments",
            SUM(p.amount) AS "payments' amount"
      FROM public.customer c 
        JOIN rental r ON r.customer_id = c.customer_id 
        JOIN inventory i ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id 
        JOIN film f ON f.film_id = i.film_id
        JOIN payment p ON p.rental_id = r.rental_id 
      WHERE r.rental_date BETWEEN left_boundary AND right_boundary 
        AND c.customer_id = i_client_id
      GROUP BY c.customer_id, "customer's info"
    )
    SELECT u.*
    FROM cte_activity a
      cross join lateral jsonb_each(to_jsonb(a) - 'customer_id') as u;
$$;
```